# Get list of file names from directory

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Im trying to get a list of files from a directory on the machine running ansible, but without the full file path up to the file name.
So far, I have

```yaml
managed_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', '../rules/*', wantlist=True) }}
```

which will return a list of files in the rules directory, but with the full path to the file, eg. `/path/to/rules/rule1.yml`, when I only want `rule1.yml`.

I would like to do something like:

```yaml
managed_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', '../rules/*', wantlist=True) | basename | list }}"
```

but this gives an error that `basename` expects a path-like string, and not a list.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) to apply the `basename` filter on all the elements of the list:

```yaml
managed_files: >-
  {{ 
    lookup('fileglob', '../rules/*', wantlist=True) 
    | map('basename') 
    | list 
  }}
```

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >- 
      {{ 
        lookup('fileglob', '../rules/*', wantlist=True) 
        | map('basename') 
        | list 
      }}
```

This yields:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - rule3.yml
  - rule1.yml
  - rule2.yml
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much for the prompt response!